AWS Glue 5.0.0 sbt dependency unavailable
Hello im trying install aws glue 5.0.0 but it does not seem to be released in https://aws-glue-etl-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com, any idea where to get the maven/sbt dependency like
"com.amazonaws" % "AWSGlueETL" % "4.0.0" % Provided excludeAll(
    ExclusionRule("com.amazonaws", "AWSSDKGlueJavaClient"),
    ExclusionRule("org.eclipse.jetty", "*")
  )


Looks like it wasn't published yet in the aws-glue-libs - releases. Also there is an open issue for Glue 5.0 artifacts not available #216. As you also see in aws-glue-etl artifacts it's only published up to version 4.0.0
